# Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

So I am sort of new to webpack since I never created my own workflow and I am trying to set up an enviorement to compile ES2015+ JS and SCSS code now for the first time. For some reason when I try to compile my webpack I get the error `Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'`. Yet I have installed it with `npm install`

**Webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './components/js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './dist/main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"}
        ],


    }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webpack",
  "main": "components/js/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.39",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7):

Alright after some digging I've found the problem. The problem is that I've installed a newer version of babel, `@babel/preset-env` which is babel version 7. Version 6 isn't working that way (as I believe, not sure) and for version 6 you have to run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env` instead of `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env` as I did.

The .babelrc file becomes

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me for babel 7.

> Inside .babelrc file

```
{
"presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

> https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/616#issuecomment-386107677

Edit:
This also works.

`{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Babel 7, I believe your .babelrc file should have the following or similar:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Babel Docs:
https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Click the Node button and see the steps.
Observation *.babelrc* file that I also tried did not work for me with :

```
   {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

but worked with : *babel.config.json* file, instead.

Comment: Another version of solving the problem: 1)npm install --save-dev @babel/core
2)npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
3) add to package.json  :    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "type": "module"

Comment: If you added this as an answer, humans would have been able to read it.